# My repeater doesn't work even when added to the router whitelist

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, repeater, wireless-extender

When I use whitelist in my router, my repeater doesn't work even with its MAC address added to the router whitelist.

Perviously (before using a whitelist), I noticed that my repeater has a different MAC address than the one on its back. I also added this MAC address to the whitelist but the same problem exists.

Note: My repeater only extends the wifi range with the same name and password and don't affect my devices MAC addresses at all. I know Mac addresses are fixed but I've read about something like that here on this link:

https://kb.netgear.com/25714/How-do-I-connect-devices-to-my-extender-if-MAC-Address-Filtering-or-Access-Control-Feature-ACL-is-enabled-on-my-router

Router: WE VDSL (Model: ZXHN H168N)
Repeater: TP-LINK (Model: TL-WR743ND)

Comment: Please add the make/model of both the main router and the signal extender to the question.

Comment: I have updated the question and added the router and repeater models ... Router: WE VDSL (Model: ZXHN H168N) Repeater: TP-LINK (Model: TL-WR743ND)